# chain rule with laplacian question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

say I had a function $P(x,y)$ and I know that $\dfrac{\partial ^2 P}{\partial x^2} = - \dfrac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2}$ and wanted to show that $ P(x,-y)$ satisfied $   \Delta P(x,-y)$ (i.e. the lapacian of $P(x,-y)$) how would I go about doing that?

My first thoughts was thatI need to show that $\dfrac{\partial^2 P}{\partial (-y)^2} = \dfrac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2}$ so I started with $\dfrac{ \partial P }{\partial (-y)} = \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial (y)} \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial (-y)}$ and then I used the product rule to differentiate again but I'm not sure how to deal with the $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial (-y)}$ and $\dfrac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial (-y)^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we need to show that $   \bigtriangleup P(x,-y)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}P(x,-y)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}P(x,-y)=0$.

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}P(x,-y)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}P(x,y)$.
For $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}P(x,-y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial (-y)}P(x,-y)\frac{\partial(-y)}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(x,-y)$. Similarly for second partial derivative. Then use the assumption and we can get the result.

Comment: Doing that I manage to get that $\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial (-y)^2} = - \dfrac{ \partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} $ which doesn't give the right value